# How to redirect the customer to the success page after Payment from Stripe?

Tags: django, api, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am using Stripe to handle my payments for my own rental website. (Backend - DJANGO)

Previously, I was using Stripe ChargesAPI and was manually sending out payouts to the Host of the property but I came to know that it can be automated by using Stripe PaymentIntentsAPI.

I have successfully managed to onboard my customers to receive payments in their bank accounts using Stripe Express.

After creating the payment intent and passing to the client I can charge their account as well as update my database for the booking.

The problem I am facing here is after the payment is done, I want to redirect the customer to the success page or payment failure page which I was able to do it by passing my reservation ID and updating it as `payment received` which I now do by using Webhooks.

How can redirect my customer to the success page showing the receipt of the booking?

[image: After Payment Completion]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to setup Payment Intent using a custom payment flow.

Briefly, how it works:

1. Capture your user's credit/debit card information and send a request to Stripe to authorize the card. If any additional verification checks are needed, Stripe provides you with an easy way to handle this
2. After authorization is complete, you capture the payment
3. If payment is successful, you show the user a success page, if not you show them an error message
   [image]

Here's a link to the documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=elements